# Collection changing variable type, using Access & VBA

Tags: ms-access, collections, types, vba

I am using a Collection to store the variable of Type `SubForm` but when I go to retrieve the object, it is of type `Controls`. Can someone tell me why this is?

```
For Each ctl In Me.controls
        Select Case ctl.ControlType
            Case acSubform
                Debug.Print "subform: " & TypeName(ctl)
                If (ctl.Name = "a" Or ctl.Name = "b") Then
                    frmCollection.Add (ctl)
                End If
        End Select
Next

For Each frm In frmCollection
    Debug.Print "Control: " & TypeName(frm)
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subform is a type of control.  Based on context, `TypeName()` seems to return either the general or specific type, but I don't understand how it makes that choice.

However, you may find `TypeOf` useful to determine whether or not `frm` is a subform.

```
For Each frm In frmCollection
    If TypeOf frm Is SubForm Then
        Debug.Print "Control is a subform"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Control is not a subform"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you. Another problem is the objects out of the collection have lost their correct properties e.g. frm.Name is not recognised anymore. It is my understanding that casts cannot be made in VBA?

Comment: In my testing I'm not seeing `frm` lose its `.Name` property.  That makes me wonder how you're declaring `frm`: Control; Object; Variant; something else?

Comment: Please elaborate about casts cannot be made in VBA.  I'm completely lost with that point.